# JS: Carmichael number

Tags: javascript, math, primes

I wrote a small carmichael algorithm but it return than 561 isn't a carmichael number.
You can see a working demo of the algorithm here: [dam.io/mt10](http://dam.io/mt10)

```
   function carmichaelTest(n) {
        if(!isPrime(n)){
            factors = isPrimeFactorListUnique(n);
            if(factors != false){
                for(var i=0;i < factors.length;i++){
                    if( n-1 % factors[i]-1 != 0){
                        return "Not a carmichael number:"+(n-1)+" % "+(factors[i]-1) +" == " + (n-1 % factors[i]-1 ) + "( != 0)";
                    }
                }
                return "Carmichael number!"
            }
            return "Not carmichael number: factors: "+primeFactorList(n);
        }else{
            return "Prime so not carmichael number";
        }
        return "Humm...";
    }
```

And It's not for a course, just for fun.

EDIT: Also, as the condition, I tried also:

```
if(rapidExpo(factors[i],n-1,n) != 1){
```

and

```
if(factors[i]-1 % n-1 != 0){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If found the error, the condition was just mispelled, it was

```
((n-1) % (factors[i]-1)) != 0
```

Comment: You should accept your answer now, it will be cleaner and you'll get a shiny badge.

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot this question